is this hole in balcony useful?
Before I fill this hole with foam, is it actually here on purpose? There are three of them on my balcony at different points where the wall meets the floor, and I can't think of a reason they would be useful.
There is also  a large drainage hole in the corner that I'm fairly certain is for water runoff from balconies above. It's a new building (2020), 16 floors.



On a balcony, if the sliders go directly to the outside, (not from living area to balcony) they can be drain holes.

Give us some context. You can't ask whether Kareem can dunk and just show his shoes.

Does the full photo help? I'm not sure what form of context to provide, so if there's something specific you need, just ask.

I would second them being drain/weep holes.  They allow moisture/water to escape to the outside.

As others have said, it looks like a weep hole, to let any water that gets past the caulking drain out before it can become a bigger problem.
Bottoms of windows are often either left uncaulked, or have drain holes drilled into them, or both. Think of that door as a very large sliding window.
